# two scrollable textareas

Tags: javascript, textarea

How i can i have two text areas next to each other with the same number of lines; where when i scroll the first the second will move along as well and vice versa.

This will be used for the idea of having line numbers or any other string before the text area. Of course the only way around this is via javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the approach described in the [Synchronize Scrolling of Two TextArea or Multiline ASP.NET TextBoxes using jQuery](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/09/synchronize-scrolling-of-two-textarea.html) article to accomplish this task.

Comment: not working in opera. also only works when moving one of the bars